# Use `.dir-locals.el' to append to `before-save-hook' as a buffer local variable

Tags: hooks, buffer-local

I want to use `.dir-locals.el` to append to the `before-save-hook` in a project for c++ files.

Currently I'm using:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'clang-format-buffer nil t)))
```

This will set `before-save-hook` as a *buffer local variable* ignoring everything that I set globally.

*How can I create a buffer-local variable of 'before-save-hook' that takes the value from the global version and then adds `clang-format-buffer`?*

Another thing that is a little bit annoying is that this will only be applied after the second file I open in the project. In the first cpp file that I open the hook is not applied.

Comment: If it doesn't have to go to `before-save-hook`, you can add it to `local-write-file-hooks` which is buffer local by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'clang-format-buffer nil t)
```

This is the right way to add a function locally to a hook.

> This will set before-save-hook as a buffer local variable ignoring everything that I set globally.

No, it won't. The global value will still exist, and **`run-hooks` will run both values**.
`before-save-hook` is no exception here, try it out and you will see. Nothing will get ignored.

> Another thing that is a little bit annoying is that this will only be applied after the second file I open in the project. In the first cpp file that I open the hook is not applied.

This is what your `.dir-locals.el` should look like:

```
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((c++-mode
  (eval add-hook 'before-save-hook #'clang-format-buffer nil t)))
```

Comment: With some more looking around, from `add-hook` documentation: *The optional fourth argument, LOCAL, if non-nil, says to modify the hook's buffer-local value rather than its global value. This makes the hook buffer-local, and it makes t a member of the buffer-local value.* ***That acts as a flag to run the hook functions of the global value as well as in the local value.***

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware that this will add a new `before-save-hook` that is independent from the global value.

Comment: The difference between the line in the question and the answer seems to be the hash. Is the `#` important here?

Comment: @JayeshBadwaik there's no difference. I just corrected the OP's understanding of what it does.

Comment: Okay, cool. :-)