# Is there a way to undo hook attached to major modes in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, hooks, directory-local-variables

In my `.spacemacs` file I set the following hooks to run:

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'prettier-js-mode)
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'prettier-js-mode)
```

I, however, have projects where I don't want these to run. I'd like to unset them in a `.dir-locals.el` file. However, I've yet to be able to do that. I found [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12433/use-dir-locals-el-to-append-to-before-save-hook-as-a-buffer-local-variable) stackexchange question about *adding* hooks.

Based on that I tried this in my `.dir-local.el` file:

```
((js-mode
  (eval remove-hook 'before-save-hook 'prettier-js-mode nil f)))
```

This, however, failed to toggle *off* the prettier-js-mode. It occurs to me that the problem here is that `.dir-locals.el` may be better suited to setting variables than setting/un-setting hooks.

If that's the case, what is the right strategy for unsetting hooks for particular project(s)?

Comment: `remove-hook` takes three arguments (see its doc string with `C-h f remove-hook`). Try this (untested): `((js-mode
  (eval remove-hook 'before-save-hook 'prettier-js-mode  t)))`